# Tortoise SVN revert one change only in a file's changeset, is it possible?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In the Tortoise SVN diff viewer, when viewing the changes one has made to a particular file, can any one change be reverted (meaning I want to keep the other changes just revert one that I don't want)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer, I'm posting it here in case anyone else in the future needs to know. When looking at one individual file's diff using Tortoise SVN's diff/merge viewer, one can right click on individual changes and/or lines of individual multiline changes and select `Mark this change`. Then later, once only the needed changes have been marked, one can select 'Leave only marked changes' from the same menu, thereby ignoring all unmarked(and hence undesired) changes.